# Cargar componente en función de resultado de server

Tags: reactjs

Me gustaría saber como cargar una clase con varios componentes, dependiendo del resultado de consulta a servidor.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import {  Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Contents from './Contents';


class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleloginClick = this.handleloginClick.bind(this);
        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
          show: true,
          username: "",
          password: "",
        };
      }

      handleloginClick(event) {
      var parametros = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }


      $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: "/react/login.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

        }
      });   
  }

    handleUsernameChange(event) {
        this.setState({username: event.target.value});
    }

    handlePasswordChange(event) {
      this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }


  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }
     render() {
       /*if(1+1==2){
           return (<Redirect to={'./Contents'} />);
       }*/

        return (
          <>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Identificaci&oacute;n</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>   <div className="modal-body">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="control-label label-default">Usuario:</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control input-sm" id="usr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} value={this.state.username}   required />
                  </div>
                   <div className="form-group label-default">
                  <label  className="control-label">Clave:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control input-sm" id="pass" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} value={this.state.password}  required />
                  </div>
              </div>           </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                  Cerrar
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary"  onClick={this.handleloginClick}>
                  Aceptar
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
          </>
        );
      }
  }
  export default Login;
```

Es un modal con dos campos que al hacer click en aceptar llama al servidor y este responde con un -1 o 0. Segun la respuesta, me gustaría cerrar el modal y cargar la clase Contents dentro de Contens.js que sera la que me cargue la pagina principal. Header, body, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puede hacer es: cuando la respuesta respuesta es positiva utiliza el objeto la funcion props.history.push('/content'), esto se puede hacer utilizando react-router-dom, sino no lo utiliza puede crear otra propiedad en en el state que sean isContent: false y cuando la respuesta es positiva actualiza el state poniendo el modal en false y el isContent en true y en el render puede ser algo asi.

import Content from './Content'
Class Login {
render() {
        return this.state.isContnent ? () : (
          <>
        
              
                Identificación
              
                 
                
                  Usuario:
                  
                  
                   
                  Clave:
                  
                  
                         
              
                
                  Cerrar
                
                
                  Aceptar
                
              
            
          
        );
      }
}

Comment: He puesto history.push('/Contents'), en el evento success pero me da un error, no se si al usar push, tengo que instalar algo.... El error es Unexpected token (34:8). Decir que importo Contents

Comment: Para utilizar el push debes utilizar el react-router-dom, puedes ver si tienes el push imprimiendo los props en el componente Login.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener una estructura así para implementar el push.

Archivo

App.jsx

import {
  Route,
BrowserRouter
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'

.....todo lo de la clase y en el render poner

Asi puede utilizar el objeto history, porque ademas ya tiene registrada la ruta.